# What is default behaviour of MediaRecorder.start() if timeslice argument is not passed?

Tags: javascript, media, web-mediarecorder

I use [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) for recording media on browser.

For starting recording I need to call [`MediaRecorder.start()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start) this method take `timeslice` as argument set number of milliseconds to record into each [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

I want to know what is behaviour in case we are not setting `timeslice`? What would be chunk/blob size by default?

Comment: From the MDN link you posted: "*If this parameter isn't included, the entire media duration is recorded into a single `Blob` unless the `requestData()` method is called to obtain the `Blob` and trigger the creation of a new `Blob` into which the media continues to be recorded.*"